# Is it possible to get the number of rows with content present in excel sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried using like this,

```
sheet.get_highest_row()
```

but the output was `104578`

I have only 3 rows in my excel sheet. I need to select only the number of rows present in the Excel sheet

Comment: What do you see if you `print sheet.calculate_dimension()` ?

Comment: `calculate_dimension()` can be used to check the actual cells in a worksheet but it does not distinguish between empty and non-empty cells. Whichever application created the file decided that there should be 104578 rows (often for formatting purposes). openpyxl 2.3 will restrict itself to counting only rows with cells.

Comment: @CharlieClark it didnt work. the output was `A1:AMK1048576`

Comment: So, you've got that many rows in your workbook. You'll have to write your own code to find empty rows.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in Excel and press Ctrl-End. This will select the last cell according to Excel. This is probably an empty cell somewhere in row 104578. If this is the case, select all empty rows in Excel, delete and save. This should update the last row.

Comment: And what if he doesn't have Excel installed?

Comment: I have to dynamically append and remove data from the excel sheet. So deleting all empty rows seems to impossible as per my usage.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of rows, you simply get the property `max_row` from the worksheet object:

```
rows = sheet.max_row
print(rows)
```

In your case, it prints `3`.